# How to iterate through dataframe rows, split data to separate dataframes based on column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've looked at iterrows, list comprehension, dictionary comprehension, apply, and itertuples. I cannot get any of those to do the scenario below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example original dataframe:

```
ID  |State  |Invoice|Price|Email 
1000|Texas  |1      |2    |texas@test.com
1000|Texas  |2      |5    |texas@test.com
1001|Alabama|3      |4    |alabama@test.com
1000|Texas  |4      |8    |texas@test.com
1002|Georgia|5      |3    |georgia@test.com
1001|Alabama|6      |6    |alabama@test.com
```

**Expected result** Iterate through original dataframe, pull by ID to include all data to separate dataframes.

DF1:

```
ID  |State  |Invoice|Price|Email 
1000|Texas  |1      |2    |texas@test.com
1000|Texas  |2      |5    |texas@test.com
1000|Texas  |4      |8    |texas@test.com
```

Df2:

```
ID  |State  |Invoice|Price|Email
1001|Alabama|3      |4    |alabama@test.com
1001|Alabama|6      |6    |alabama@test.com
```

Df3:

```
ID  |State  |Invoice|Price|Email
1002|Georgia|5      |3    |georgia@test.com
```

Comment: `for _, i in df.groupby("ID"): print (i)`. Or `{n:i for n, i in df.groupby("ID")}` as a dict.

Comment: @HenryYik I used "for n, i in df.groupby("ID"): print (i)" and it took the first ID and split out all of the associated rows and data into a new DF. How can I get it to continue through the original dataframe to continue pulling the additional rows into their own dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a dictionary that has each dataframe split out by ID using the following code:

```
dict_of_dfs = {

    ID: group_df 

    for ID, group_df in df.groupby('ID') 

}
```

I was also able to create a list that has each dataframe split out by ID using the following code:

```
list_of_dfs = [

    group_df 

    for _, group_df in df.groupby('ID')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the grouper from `pd.groupby` -

```
df1, df2, df3 = [i[1] for i in df.groupby(['ID'])]
```

Using the conditions with `pd.Series.unique` -

```
df1, df2, df3 = [df[df['ID']==i] for i in df['ID'].unique()]
```

Outputs for each method -

```
df1
     ID  State  Invoice  Price           Email
0  1000  Texas        1      2  texas@test.com
1  1000  Texas        2      5  texas@test.com
3  1000  Texas        4      8  texas@test.com

#df2
     ID    State  Invoice  Price             Email
2  1001  Alabama        3      4  alabama@test.com
5  1001  Alabama        6      6  alabama@test.com

#df3
     ID    State  Invoice  Price             Email
4  1002  Georgia        5      3  georgia@test.com
```